# Some character didn't post with Json Post - getting 500 reponse

Tags: android, json, api, post, asp.net-web-api

I have prepared one API, and I want to send one specific data with json posting.

My code works fine during working with Fiddler or site side.

But the problem is why some character didn't send, when we use Android version as a client device.

For example:

string a="mn✈" // correct on any device (android,site,Fiddler,...)

string b="mn✉" //correct on any device except(android) //getting 500 reponse

```
String requestURL = Utils.SERVER_URL + "PostJsonFeatures";
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(requestURL).openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("Features", getAttributes());
            postDataParams.put("productId", productId);
            postDataParams.put("groupId", catId);
            postDataParams.put("brandId", PrefManager.getInstance(context).getCompanyId());
            postDataParams.put("languageId", PrefManager.getInstance(context).getLanguageApi());

            DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream ());
            printout.write(postDataParams.toString().getBytes());
            printout.flush ();
            printout.close ();
```

Comment: put your code here

Comment: @Singh it'd edited

Comment: You can decode string while send in web api

Comment: @Singh , how can I decode it ?, is this help ?

Comment: String parseString = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(myString, "UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: @Singh Thank you, it helped , add it to answers and I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode to string and pass in url.

```
String parseString = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(myString, "UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
```